# Visualization and vectorizing for AI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, vectorization, reducers, deep-learning, palette

I'm glad to find this space, I come from a background in economics and do not know the first thing about GIS (hope to learn as I go with this project).

I found an interesting dataset (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NASA_ORNL_biomass_carbon_density_v1) about biomass, and upon clicking on the Snippet button, a Code Editor is launched with this code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/ORNL/biomass_carbon_density/v1");

var visualization = {
  bands: ['agb'],
  min: -50.0,
  max: 80.0,
  palette: ['d9f0a3', 'addd8e', '78c679', '41ab5d', '238443', '005a32']
};

Map.setCenter(-60.0, 7.0, 4);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, "Aboveground biomass carbon");
```

... which displays a map with classic Google palette. But if I remove the palette property, I get a map on a grayscale, where regions like Amazonia are extremely white and regions like Sahara are extremely black, so I suppose this is the authentic representation of the band I am interested in, AboveGround Biomass or abg.

My goal is to train an AI that can assess how much biomass there is in a satellite image. I think I need to use as inputs images in a "standard" palette, that way I can more easily find current images to test it. So I am thinking in using visualize() passing the palette to generate inputs images and using the abg band from the original dataset as label to train the model.

Is this theoretically sound? I am just not sure if changing the palette generates a representation that can be compared with images obtained from other sources, even if they were "generated" using this palette.

Comment: It sounds like you have two different goals — a collection of polygons (in KML) and an image with continuous values are very different data formats and the setup to produce them will be different. Can you [edit] your question to explain how you want these to precisely relate to each other? This will help us give a precise useful answer. If you have two separate problems — one a vector visualization and one an image for training data — then it would be better to post them as separate questions.

Comment: Hi! I guess I don't neccessarily need the KMLs, maybe I can generate the images with the palette I want and vectorize using the tools provided by the AI framework. I wanted a KML to see how the images generated after applying the palette look like, because I can't train with images using the original band if I intend to test with other datasets.

So my main concern is if the approach I am considering makes sense. I want to use the values for the original band as the label and the images with the palette as the inputs. I imagine it's not a big deal to iterate over the original collection.